# Caffe not importing in python

Tags: python, import, module, installation, caffe

Ubuntu 18.04

Python 2.7

My issue is I am unable to import caffe module in python even though I have installed it. I believe it is a path / env variable issue.

```
rivaldo4t@Rivaldo-OS3:~$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named caffe
```

As referred from [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html), I ran the command `sudo apt install caffe-cpu` for installing pre-compiled Caffe and it did successfully. When I type in caffe in the terminal, I get something like

```
rivaldo4t@Rivaldo-OS3:~$ caffe
caffe: command line brew
usage: caffe <command> <args>

commands:
  train           train or finetune a model
  test            score a model
  device_query    show GPU diagnostic information
  time            benchmark model execution time
```

Which means caffe is installed correctly. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/720), I tried to set my `PYTHONPATH` variable to the location of Caffe install directory. So I did this,

```
rivaldo4t@Rivaldo-OS3:~$ which caffe
/usr/bin/caffe
```

When I tried to run echo $PYTHONPATH, it showed up to be empty (I still don't know why). Then I tried to update the path using

```
caffe_root = '/usr/bin/caffe/python'
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root)
```

So now I get this when I print sys.path -

```
rivaldo4t@Rivaldo-OS3:~$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/home/rivaldo4t', '/usr/bin/caffe/python', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/rivaldo4t/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

But I am still unable to import caffe in python. Another thing I noticed was /usr/bin/caffe is not a directory and I can't understand where is caffe installed if not here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install caffe on ubuntu using `sudo apt install caffe-cpu`, it compiles the bindings for python 3 only (`_caffe.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`), which is located at `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/caffe/`. So the short answer is to use python 3 instead.

The long answer is to compile caffe with python 2 bindings from source.